# Expression simplification in SymPy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I want to achieve this kind of simplification:
`e+ac+ad+bc+bd = e+(a+b)(c+d)` . None of SymPy simplification functions worked this way. Is there any other method in SymPy or somewhere else in python to get this kind of simplification?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `collect(expr, e, func=factor)`.

```
In [5]: expr = e + a*c + a*d + b*c + b*d

In [6]: collect(expr, e, func=factor)
Out[6]: e + (a + b)⋅(c + d)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it for general case. For example if we don't know that name of first variable is "e"? Or if we don't know name of any variable?

Comment: In general you need to know something about the way that you want to do this "partial" factorization. Such a thing is not well defined as there are generally many ways that you can factor different parts an expression (as opposed to factoring the whole expression, which is always unique).

Comment: Is it possible to make same kind of simplification if instead of "e" we have any symbol from other part of expression? For example  a + a*c + a*d + b*c + b*d = a + (a + b)⋅(c + d). Above method doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @GiorgiBakhtadze I think you'd have to replace `c + d` with a single symbol, like `expr.subs(c, x - d)` and collect on that.