# sympy: simplify a larger expression with Binomial formula and quadratic complement

Tags: python, sympy

I get some eigenvalues of the matrix

```
import sys
import mpmath
from sympy import *

X,Y,Z = symbols("X,Y,Z")
Rxy,Rxz, Ry,Ryx,Ryz, Rz,Rzy,Rzz = symbols("Rxy,Rxz,  Ry,Ryx,Ryz, Rz,Rzy,Rzz")


J = Matrix([
       [      -1,        0,        0],
       [       0,    -Ry*Y, Ry*Rzy*Y],
       [Rxz*Rz*Z, Ryz*Rz*Z,    -Rz*Z]])
```

which are the following:

```
{-Ry*Y/2 - Rz*Z/2 + sqrt(Ry**2*Y**2 + 4*Ry*Ryz*Rz*Rzy*Y*Z - 2*Ry*Rz*Y*Z + Rz**2*Z**2)/2: 1,
 -Ry*Y/2 - Rz*Z/2 - sqrt(Ry**2*Y**2 + 4*Ry*Ryz*Rz*Rzy*Y*Z - 2*Ry*Rz*Y*Z + Rz**2*Z**2)/2: 1,
 -1: 1}
```

lets just look at eigenvalue one:

```
In [25]: J.eigenvals().keys()[0]
Out[25]: -Ry*Y/2 - Rz*Z/2 + sqrt(Ry**2*Y**2 + 4*Ry*Ryz*Rz*Rzy*Y*Z - 2*Ry*Rz*Y*Z + Rz**2*Z**2)/2
```

I want to simplify this term the following: factor out 1/2 and (this is important)  the radicant.

I can transform the radicant as following by adding the quadratic complement

```
Ry**2*Y**2 + 4*Ry*Ryz*Rz*Rzy*Y*Z - 2*Ry*Rz*Y*Z + Rz**2*Z**2     | + 4*Ry*Rz*Y*Z -4*Ry*Rz*Y*Z
```

which leads to

```
Ry**2*Y**2 + Rz**2*Z**2 + 2*Ry*Rz*Y*Z - 4*Ry*Rz*Y*Z + 4*Ry*Ryz*Rz*Rzy*Y*Z
```

which can be factorized to

```
(Ry*Y + Rz*Z)**2 - 4*Ry*Rz*Y*Z*(1 - Ryz*Rzy)
```

with these evaluations the complete eigenvalue should look like this

```
-1/2*(Ry*Y + Rz*Z - sqrt((Ry*Y + Rz*Z)**2 - 4*Ry*Rz*Y*Z*(1 - Ryz*Rzy)))
```

This calculation is really important for me because I have to evaluate if the eigenvalue is <0. Which is much easier in the last form.

Let me show you what I did until now.

```
In [24]: J.eigenvals().keys()[0]
Out[24]: -Ry*Y/2 - Rz*Z/2 + sqrt(Ry**2*Y**2 + 4*Ry*Ryz*Rz*Rzy*Y*Z - 2*Ry*Rz*Y*Z + Rz**2*Z**2)/2

In [25]: J.eigenvals().keys()[0].factor() 
Out[25]: -(Ry*Y + Rz*Z - sqrt(Ry**2*Y**2 + 4*Ry*Ryz*Rz*Rzy*Y*Z - 2*Ry*Rz*Y*Z + Rz**2*Z**2))/2

In [26]: J.eigenvals().keys()[0].simplify()
Out[26]: -Ry*Y/2 - Rz*Z/2 + sqrt(Ry**2*Y**2 + 4*Ry*Ryz*Rz*Rzy*Y*Z - 2*Ry*Rz*Y*Z + Rz**2*Z**2)/2
```

So .simplify() doesnt changes the result at all.
.factor() just factors out the -1/2. 
 If I remember correct, I can pass an argument to .factor() like Y or Z, which variable should be factorized. But I get a lot of slightly different eigenvalues as output and I don't want to specify each argument of factor() by hand (if this solution even works).

I also tried to calculate the eigenvalues by myself by calculating the determinant and solve determinat==0...
I also used determinat.factor() and solved it afterwards but the best result of this approach was the same as J.eigenvals().keys()[0].factor().

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Alex

Comment: `factor` in SymPy means "factor into a product of polynomials". So it will only work if you give it the subset of terms that factor into a product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of thing is asked for a lot (see also, for instance, this question: [Expression simplification in SymPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620585/expression-simplification-in-sympy/40643065)), but there isn't really a good way in SymPy to do it.  The problem is that such "partial" factorizations are not unique (there may be multiple ways to convert a polynomial into a sum of products).

I opened [this issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11869) about it in the SymPy issue tracker. I showed there a way that you can get close (here `a` is the term under the square root)

```
In [92]: collect(expand(a.subs(Ry*Y, x - Rz*Z)), x, func=factor).subs(x, Ry*Y + Rz*Z)
Out[92]:
      2  2                                                                   2
- 4⋅Rz ⋅Z ⋅(Ryz⋅Rzy - 1) + 4⋅Rz⋅Z⋅(Ry⋅Y + Rz⋅Z)⋅(Ryz⋅Rzy - 1) + (Ry⋅Y + Rz⋅Z)
```

Here I am temporarily replacing `Ry*Y + Rz*Z` with a variable `x` so that I can get the squared term that you want.

I couldn't figure out a way to get closer to exactly what you want (i.e., factor the `Ryz*Rzy - 1` out of the remaining terms).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately I'm writing a script, where the resulting expression differs from time to time. Well I think I have to simplify my expressions by hand.
--Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how far this can take someone doing the same thing, but here is something to experiment with:

```py
def scollect(eq, s):
    """collect on a 2-term sum that is expected to appear
    as a factor in a sum.

    Examples
    ========

    >>> from sympy import symbols, expand

    >>> (Rz, Rzy, Ryz, Ry, Z, Y) = symbols('Rz, Rzy, Ryz, Ry, Z, Y')
    >>> f = Ry**2*Y**2 + 4*Ry*Ryz*Rz*Rzy*Y*Z - 2*Ry*Rz*Y*Z + Rz**2*Z**2
    >>> scollect(f, Ry*Y + Rz*Z)
    4*Ry*Rz*Y*Z*(Ryz*Rzy - 1) + (Ry*Y + Rz*Z)**2

    >>> from sympy.abc import a, b, c, d, e, f
    >>> h = a*c + a*d + a + b*c + b*d
    >>> scollect(h, c + d)
    a + (a + b)*(c + d)
    >>> (_ - a)*(b + c) + a
    a + (a + b)*(b + c)*(c + d)
    >>> scollect(_, c + d)
    a + (a + b)*(b + c)*(c + d)
    >>> scollect(_.expand(),c+d)
    a + (a + b)*(b + c)*(c + d)
    """
    from sympy import factor_terms, collect, Dummy, factor, cse
    assert s.is_Add and len(s.args) == 2
    x = Dummy()
    eq = eq.subs(s.args[0], x - s.args[1]).expand()
    eq = collect(eq, x, func=factor)
    r, e = cse(eq)
    for o, n in r:
        if n.is_Add:
            eq = collect(e[0], o).subs(o, n)
            if eq.is_Add:
                eq = sum(factor_terms(i) for i in eq.args)
            break
    return eq.subs(x, s)
```